# Add all elements with each other in array in O(n) time

Tags: loops, math, recursion

Suppose an array consist of 3 elements:

```
 A=[1,2,3]
```

What I want to know is that, is it possible to add each element of array with each other such that time complexity is O(n)?.
Result should have

```
b=[(1+1),(1+2),(1+3),(2+2),(2+3),(3+3)]
```

Answer (score 5):

No, that's `O(n^2)`.

Now let's see someone prove me wrong ... even better, someone has proven my assertion right -- see the comments below.

Comment: More precisely, an algorithm cannot have a runtime complexity in terms of the input that is strictly smaller than the length of the output in terms of the input...

Comment: This algorithm generates all subsets of size `2` from a set of size `n`. The count of these sets is the binomial coefficient `(n  k)` with `k = 2` which is exactly: `n(n-1)/2`, which proves your statement correct.